# Package manager command that returns 0 or 1 in Ubuntu/Debian if a package is installed or not

Tags: perl, ubuntu, debian, package

I'm writing a package installer script in Perl.  I need a command (probably OS command) that returns a simple 0 or 1 to the caller script if a Ubuntu/Debian package is installed or not.

I've tried

```
      dpkg -s
```

It always returns 0.

```
      dpkg -L
```

almost works but if the user does not

```
      apt-get --purge remove
```

the packages, some files are left and always returns 0

I don't want to grep text - a simple true or false is what I need.
Any ideas?

@Andy:

```
   aptitude remove unixodbc -y

   dpkg-query -W unixodbc; echo $?
   unixodbc        2.2.11-21
   0

   aptitude install unixodbc -y

   dpkg-query -W unixodbc; echo $?
   unixodbc        2.2.11-21
   0
```

Comment: But `grep` does return a simple true or false.

Comment: @ikegami There has to be simple package manager command that returns 0 or 1.  If the text I grep changes and my program is in the world, all of my programs will fail - not an option.

Comment: The package states are documented. If they change, that would be a violation of their documentation.

Comment: @ikegami The problem when you grep text is that the text can change.  A space here a period there and your regex stops working.  There is no assertion that someone won't change the text output.

Comment: Search engine fodder: with the standard packaging system, it's `rpm -qi packagename packagename`. Return value is 0 if all named packages are installed, else 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not ideal, but this works:

```
dpkg -s "$package" | grep '^Status:' | grep -q ' installed'
```

Or just

```
dpkg -s "$package" | grep -q '^Status:.* installed'
```

Comment: @bitbucket sometimes you have to reject elegance in favour of function.

Comment: @CanSpice This cannot be the canonical way to query if a package is installed -- there has to be a a simpler way.

Comment: grep -q can be used to make the /dev/null redirection unnecessary

Comment: @ysth, I thought `grep -q` hid errors too, but  that's not the case ona new reading of the man page. Fixed.

Comment: is there some reason not to do a single grep?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does it:

```
test -n "`aptitude search '?name(^packagename$)~i'`"
```

Won't work on virtual packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the dpkg database, I concur with the "use grep" suggestions. Weighing the possibility that the output format of the package tools changes against the complexity of the alternative solutions, it's probably better to use grep.

That said, here are some possibilities:

1. use `dpkg --get-selections`. The exit status is always zero, but the output is very simple: `<package><white space><status>`. This is the "requested state" (install/hold/deinstall/purge), which can differ from the actual package state, but usually won't.
2. use one of the utilities in the `dctrl-tools` or `dpkg-awk` packages
3. implement a test that directly determines whether the dependency is present, e.g., use `pkg-config`, or search for a program in `PATH`. This has the advantage that it will allow the install to continue on systems where the dependency has been built by hand and installed without the knowledge of the package manager. This also makes your install script more portable.
4. you may want to look in to [PackageKit](http://wiki.debian.org/PackageKit)